# Static analysis criteria different for various parts of solution

Tags: code-quality, tools, static-analysis

We have quite a large project where and tend to apply risk based approach to stringency of unit tests and code reviews. E.g. components classified as A need to have higher coverage than components classified as B. However, it is nearly impossible without a support of static analyser - is there a way how to instruct (e.g. Sonar) to apply different rules on different modules? Is that approach feasible, how to otherwise deal with complex projects with parts that are subject to different quality requirements?

Comment: [Where does my tool question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Comment: Right, I am sorry. But my question also concerns the approach itself.

Comment: If you had automated builds you might be able to do something with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to archive that is to create good architecture. Then you can partition your software into components. For example, in C and C++, one component can be a library. Then in tools like sonar and jenkins, you can checkout just specific components, and do with them whatever you like.

Comment: The question indicates that there are already components (*"components classified as A need [...]"*). Maybe the same term is used for different things? Moreover, having creating multiple builds just to be able to enforce different coverage levels seem like an overkill (although I don't have anything constructive to suggest instead).